# Is it possible / reasonable to stream H.264 encoded video via the Xively service?

Tags: video, streaming, xively

I see that sensor data can be streamed / accessed via the Xively service, but I'm not sure if using a video stream (from webcam) would be possible.  Is this outside the typical usage scenario for Xively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed outside of the scope of Xively V2 APIs. The more suitable approach would be to implement a peer-to-peer stream initiated via Xively, based on some value change.